# List networks in reach and connect to them

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift, wifi

I would like to make an app where I can select a wifi network, then add the pwd -> so that my phone/mac connects to it..

But i can't seem to find code that will do the following:
1. get a list of networks in reach
2. connect to a wifi network
3. insert pwd

Hope it's not to unclear..

Comment: As I know you couldn't do that

Answer (score 0):

As a general tool, this isn't possible.  The nearest approximation would be to use the `Captured Network` interfaces to connect to specific networks.